# Pandas mapping a column: Is it possible for the map function to return a dictionary for automatic column assignment?

Tags: python, pandas

Say that I have a pandas example column

```
df
a
1
2
3
4
```

Is it possible to map the column using a function that returns a dictionary, such that the dictionary keys are used for the column assignment?

Continuing with the example

The mapping function

```
def red(x):
   return {'b': x+1, 'c': x+2}
```

And the final result would be

```
df
a b c 
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
4 5 6
```

which would be achievable programmatically in python/pandas somehow

`df = df.magic_map(red)`

Comment: do columns returned by the map function overlap with existing ones?

Comment: I haven't thought of that detail, but in my example case, there is no overlap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([[1], [2]])

def func(v: int) -> dict[int, int]:
    return {1: v + 1, 2: v + 2}

a[0].map(func).apply(pd.Series)
```

And if they overlap with the existing ones then

```
new_cols = a[0].map(func).apply(pd.Series)
a.update(new_cols)
```

will overwrite the existing values if they appear in new_cols.

Also I personally think this manner is implicit. So if you can, it is better to use something like this:

```
def update_df(df: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
    df['x1'] = df['x'] + 1
    df['x2'] = df['x'] + 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you do the following?:

```py
def red(x):
   b = x + 1
   c = x + 2
   return pd.Series([b, c], index=['b', 'c'])

df = df['a'].apply(red)
```

Or this one is shorter:

```py
df = df['a'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x+1, x+2], index=['b', 'c']))
```